# Less frequent ticks on the x axis in Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a python plot, I have used xticks to tell my plot what values to put on the xaxis:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(grid_resid.shape[1]),xp_int,rotation="vertical")
```

Both **(np.arange(grid_resid.shape[1])** and **xp_int** have 1830 values each:

[   0    1    2 ..., 1827 1828 1829]

[ 53293  53294  53295 ...,  55120  55121  55122]

I have realised that I don't need a tick for each of the 1830 values. I instead want a tick only every 100 or so. I'm hoping that there's a simple way to do this.

Any help would be gratefully received. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xticks, as you see, takes two parameters. The first specifies the location of the ticks, the second the labels.

In your case, the locations happen to be integers that can be used as keys to your labels. Thus you could easily do a tick every 100:

```
locs = np.arange(grid_resid.shape[1],step=100) # locations
plt.xticks( locs, xp_int[locs], rotation="vertical" )
```

Comment: But if "locs" is a range of values, is xp_int[locs] a valid expression?

Comment: Yes; there are quite a few different indexing methods in numpy: you can use individual indexes, slices, arrays of true/false (useful for things like x[x>4]), arrays of indexes, and so on.

Comment: I get the error:     plt.xticks(locs,xp_int[locs],rotation="vertical")
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

Comment: Oh! That will happen if `xp_int` is a Python list, not a Numpy array. Try plt.xticks(locs, np.array(xp_int)[locs], rotation="vertical"), which will create a numpy array from xp_int first.